# How to display divs in loop using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This code works perfect for displaying one notification div but i want to display this notification div ten times one after another.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Show Notification</button>

<div id="container">This is First Notification</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("container")
x.className = "show";
setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); },      3000);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion

```
    function showTimes(count, times) {
  $('#container').show();
  $('.info').append("show number" + (count + 1) + "<br>");
  console.log('func');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#container').hide()
    console.log('count: ' + count + '; times: ' + times);
    if (count >= times) {
      return;
    } else {
      setTimeout(showTimes(count + 1, times), 2000);
    }
  }, 3000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    showTimes(0, 10);
});
```

jsfiddle(press RUN at the top)
https://jsfiddle.net/ShinShil/v8ftcnLz/2/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the code does not working for me. can you  little bit explain the code.

Comment: @Archana showTimes male container visible and setTimeout to function which will check if count<times, if it so it return else it will call showTimes one moreTime with count+1

Comment: @Archana I've updated the answer with valid code and jsfiddle ref. But it is use jquery, btw strongly recommend you to learn it, basics are really simple.

Comment: #Nikita thanks for the demo link. one more question is how to hide previous text before displaying next???

Comment: @Archana Look at code, `$('#container').hide()` - hides the block, if you need you can hide block, than `$('#container').html("here text you want to display")` and call showTimes(). Or if you have some blocks you can use times as an index. `var blocks = $('.container'); blocks[times].show()`